# What does this error mean in my Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

In my rails 3.2.1 app Im getting this error in my browser, when Im trying to upload a file from my machine.

```
NoMethodError in AssetsController#create

undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x00000104200ad0>
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:53:in `block in create'
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:52:in `create
```

This is the out put on the rails thin server running on my development machine:

```
Rendered assets/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 101.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started POST "/assets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-17 16:18:03 -0700
Served asset  - 404 Not Found (7ms)
Processing by AssetsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXX=", "asset"=>{"user_id"=>"1",   "uploaded_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010430e080 @original_filename="41382-450x-e_37.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content- Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[uploaded_file]\"; filename=\"41382-450x-e_37.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/P+/P+AVMPNFEyO8F-xz7UfIP++++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20120617-19438-1y1fya5>>}, "commit"=>"Create Asset"}

User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "assets" ("created_at", "updated_at",     "uploaded_file_content_type", "uploaded_file_file_name", "uploaded_file_file_size",   "uploaded_file_updated_at", "user_id") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"    [["created_at", Sun, 17 Jun 2012  23:18:03 UTC +00:00], 

["updated_at", Sun, 17 Jun 2012  23:18:03 UTC +00:00], ["uploaded_file_content_type",   "image/jpeg"], ["uploaded_file_file_name", "41382-450x-e_37.jpeg"],     

["uploaded_file_file_size", 36549], ["uploaded_file_updated_at", Sun, 17 Jun 2012  23:18:03 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving assets/23/41382-450x-e_37.jpeg
 (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x00000104200ad0>):
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:53:in `block in create'
app/controllers/assets_controller.rb:52:in `create'
```

This is what my create method in Assets controller looks like:

```
# POST /assets
# POST /assets.json
def create
 @asset = current_user.assets.new(params[:asset])

 respond_to do |format|
   if @asset.save
     format.html { redirect_to @asset, notice: 'Asset was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render json: @asset, status: :created, location: @asset }
   else
     format.html { render action: "new" }
     format.json { render json: @asset.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
```

end

Any idea what might be happening? Would really appreciate some feedback.

Thanks

---

EDIT:
Im using the AWS gem to upload the file to amazon s3 as per [this](http://codyaray.com/downloads/2012/03/How-to-Build-a-Dropbox-like-Sharing-App-using-Ruby-on-Rails.html) tutorial.
I have this config file in my app at config/s3_credentials.yml which contains my amazon s3 credentials.

Im using this code in my asset.rb file:

```
 has_attached_file :uploaded_file,
                :path => "assets/:id/:basename.:extension",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3_credentials.yml",
                :bucket => "XXXX"
```

this is my _form thats called by the view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @asset, :html=> { :multipart => true}  do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.label :UserID %>
  <%= f.input :user_id %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.label :uploaded_file, "File" %>
    <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %>
 </div>
<div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

s3_credential.yml file

```
development:
  access_key_id:"XXXXXXXXXX"
  secret_access_key:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

production:
  access_key_id:"XXXXXXXXXX"
  secret_access_key:"lG/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: Seems like the app is attempting to access a hash of some sort where a string is given. Are you using the aws gem? http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

Comment: @Yukagi: line 52 is the line in the create method code above that starts with respond_to......

Comment: @Jasper Kennis. Yes Im using gem aws. Please see edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create `@asset` from a String that you passed to the controller. Rails is expecting hashwithindifferentaccess, and then calls symbolize_keys.

Comment: @banditKing After looking at some of my old code I did this: `current_user.assets.new(params[:asset][:uploaded_file])`. Try to `raise params.to_yaml` in your create action to see if you're accessing it correctly.

Comment: I figured it out. The error was caused by this line in my code above:      ":s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3_credentials.yml"," I replaced this with

:s3_credentials => {:access_key_id => "XXXXXXXXXX", 
                                        :secret_access_key => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}, and everything worked. The problem now is that I need to figure out how to handle the keys to access AWS S3 from the app. Clearly I dont want to store these in the code.

Comment: @banditKing awesome. glad you figured it out. use environment variables for storing sensitive data you dont want in your code. `{:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_KEY']... etc`

Comment: Or for sensitive keys, use an external config file, such as nifty:config https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause a String type has no `symbolize_keys` method. This method is from Hash type only.